# Subclassing ViewPager Breaks Animation

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation

In my Android application I have an activity which uses a view pager to display 4+ pages (Fragments). I implemented buttons on each screen that move between pages by calling:

```
pager.setCurrentItem(position, true);
```

The view pager and fragments are all working as I desired. I then began looking for a solution to disable user swiping between pages so that the transition between pages in handled by the buttons only. The solution I found was mentioned in a few stackoverflow articles as well as [This Blog](http://blog.svpino.com/2011/08/disabling-pagingswiping-on-android.html) that suggest subclassing the view pager to intercept touch events to disable swiping. I followed those examples by subclassing the view pager class as follows:

```
public class ViewPager extends android.support.v4.view.ViewPager {

    private boolean enabled;

    public ViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.enabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void setSwipingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

}
```

Using the subclassed view pager and calling `setSwipingEnabled(false)` works as was desired. The user can no longer move between pages with swipe gestures and I can still move between pages via button clicks by calling `setCurrentItem(int position, boolean smoothScroll)`. However using the subclass breaks the animation between pages. When I call `setCurrentItem(position, true)` with android.support.v4.view.ViewPager I get very clean scrolling animations between pages. When I make the same call using the subclass the screen has a very brief 'flash' and then automatically draws the new page.

I would like to know how to fix the animation while retaining the ability to disable user swiping between pages. I greatly appreciate any help with this. Let me know if you need any additional information. So far I have tested using a Samsung device running 2.3.5 and an AVD emulator targeting Android 2.3.3.

**Update:**

I've tried several things hoping I might get lucky and find a solution. I looked into the source code of `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` that I'm extending and found that "MOST" of that actual scrolling code is in the `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` method. Instead of subclassing it I tried using the normal view pager and called the below to consume the touch events:

```
pager.setOnTouchListener(new View.onTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Doing this partially worked. It prevents the swipe from triggering a scroll to the next view. However the `onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` method from the android.support.v4.view.ViewPager does a small scroll as part of the intercept before passing the touch event to the `onTouchEvent()` method. Without subclassing the ViewPager I dont see any way to alter this behavior.